# Error on dataTask - "Cannot invoke 'dataTask' with an argument list of type..."

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I'm having some trouble. Check out this section of code bellow:

```
// Create a datatask and pass in the request
            let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data:NSData?, response:URLResponse?, error:Error?) in

                // Get a reference to the image view element of the cell
                let imageView = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView

                // Create an image onject from the data and assign it into the ImageView
                imageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)

            })
```

I'm getting an error on the 2nd line this is the error: [image]

How can I fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try changing `(data:NSData?, response:URLResponse?, error:Error?)` to `data, response, error`.

Comment: @OOPer Ok, so here's the updated code  let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in      Now I am getting an error - Ambiguous reference to member 'dataTask(with:completionHandler)'

Comment: @iFunnyVlogger you need to use `URLRequest` instead of `NSURLRequest`

Comment: Thanks for the help, both of you! It worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to some comments, I have an answer! I changed the "request" from an NSURLRequest to a URLRequest and I also updated the code to this:

```
  // Create a datatask and pass in the request
            let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

                // Get a reference to the image view element of the cell
                let imageView = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView

                // Create an image onject from the data and assign it into the ImageView
                imageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)

            })
```